# Difference between wildcard search and individual text search

Tags: mongodb

Is there a difference between a wildcard search index like $** and text indexes that I create for each of the fields in the collection ?

I do see a small difference in response time when I individually create text indexes. Using individual indexes, returns a better response. I am not able to post an example now, but will try to.

Answer (score 0):

A wildcard text search will index every field that contains string data for each document in the collection (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes).

Because you are essentially increasing the number of fields indexed with a wild card text index, it would take longer to run compared to targeting specific fields for a text index.

Since you can only have one text index per collection (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index), its worth considering which fields you plan on querying against beforehand.

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”